# how to cover multiple if else if in testclass?

Tags: unit-test

test class:
[image: uncovered test class]
I wrote a test class for Rfleet_PaymentConditions.but some part in if else condition not covering.anybody please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case of classic [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344305/what-is-short-circuiting-and-how-is-it-used-when-programming-in-java) in which as soon as condition is marked as true, the further evaluation stops.

What you can do is to create another test method in which you can create an account with all fields(that are used in if condition) populated except

```
acc.RFleet_deprecation_DueMonth_Period2__c
```

and then run the test.

The other thing you can do is to edit your class and evaluate a boolean variable first using the or conditions

> Boolean conditionTrue = acc.RFleet_deprecation_DueMonth_Period2__c || acc.Upper_date__c ..... etc

Then use this in:

as

```
if(conditionTrue){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would write your trigger / class a bit differently making it much easier to cover etc....

Since all the fields seem to have a "Period1__c" or "Period2__c" in them I would use describe information to evaluate if I need to enter the condition or not:

```
//Put somewhere at the top of your class
Map<String,Schema.sObjectField> fldMap = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Boolean conditionMet = false;

//Put in the acc loop
for(String fld : fldMap.keySet()){
   if(fld.endsWith('Period1__c') || fld.endsWith('Period2__c')){
      if(acc.get(fld) == null){
         conditionMet = true;
         break; 
      }
   }
}

if(conditionMet){

    .....Do Your Stuff Here.....
    conditionMet = false;

}
```

You will have to take into consideration the possibility of any other field ending in Period1__c or Period2__c. So adjust as necessary to cover the fields you are looking at. In addition, when adding new fields, if you follow the naming convention the trigger / code will automatically evaluate them.

Comment: or use a List<String> of field names to check for null (where list is populated from a custom parm object so it can be maintained outside of the code). Or maybe even a custom setting regex of valid fieldname patterns to check for null